# Use counter to add numbers to value while performing INSERT

Tags: c#, sql, counter

Right now, I have a function that inserts a new basket item into the database when it's called. What I want to change is how the [Sku] parameter is set. I want to try and use a counter variable partnered with a string value (in this case, the string value is "SetupFee") so that this Sku parameter is different for each item inserted.

For example, if there are 5 items, I would like the counter variable to add 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. to the Sku parameter so that each product has a different sku. It's kind of strange but, based on how things are set up, this is the best option. I've just never tried to use a counter as part of a query before. Any suggestions on how I can approach this?

This is the function I have:

```
     protected void UpdateBasketItems(int BasketID, string BasketItemName, decimal FeeAmount, int ProductId)
    {
        try 
        { 
            int count = 0;
            Basket basket = AbleContext.Current.User.Basket;

            IList<BasketItem> items = GetBasketItems();

            string query = "INSERT INTO ac_BasketItems ([ParentItemId], [BasketId], [BasketShipmentId], [ProductId], [TaxCodeId], [Name], [Sku], [Price], [Weight], [Quantity], [OrderItemTypeId], [OrderBy], [ShippableId], [LastModifiedDate], [TaxAmount], [TaxRate], [CreatedDate] )VALUES (0, @BasketID, (SELECT MAX(BasketShipmentId) FROM [ac_BasketItems] WHERE [BasketID] = @BasketID), 19524, 1,'" + BasketItemName + "','SetupFee'," + FeeAmount + ", 0, 1, 0, 999, 0, Current_TimeStamp, 0, 0, Current_TimeStamp)";

            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
            {
                cn.Open();                
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BasketID", BasketID));

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();

            }

        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Response.Write("ERROR with UpdateBasketItems(): " + x.Message.ToString() + "<br />");
        }
    }
```

Comment: does this counter reset after the request?  does it need to save the prev value AFTER an app restart?

Comment: Yes, it does reset, and it must save the prev value after an app restart

Comment: are you using SQL Server?

Comment: how about try string.Format on your Insert statement and increment and or set the Sku based on the Parameters + counter[position] also make sure your Sku is a VarChar and not type Int in the database better yet create a stored procedure and after each call let the stored procedure do the quick update based on the newly inserted record, based on the Returned ID which would be `@@SCOPE_IDENTITY`

Answer (score 0):

**A simple (built in feature) for MS SQL Server:**

The simplest way to do this is to create an `identity` column in the table you are inserting into.  You can get that value after the insert by using the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function.

However, if your table already has an existing identity column (one that you cannot use) you could create a Sequence table that has a single row.  That row would contain the next_seq value, upon inserting you would get that value and update + 1

Comment: or he could update the field in a stored procedure when returning @@SCOPE_IDENTITy and before exiting the stored procedure update the current record where the returned ID of the newly inserted field gets assigned to @@Scope_Identity..

Comment: if the table has an identity column defined then the value would already be assigned, he'd need to get the number only if he needed to do something with it in his c# code.

Comment: he wouldn't know the last updated / inserted row unless he's assigning @@Scope_Identity which I am currently doing the same thing regardless he said he wants to assign it based on the insert .. so he would still need to use an UPDate Statement if the row inserted is Auto Increment field.. it's easier in my opinion to do all the work from within a storedProc

Comment: I agree with you sproc is the way to go.

Comment: I am not disagreeing with your just adding more information that might make what seems like a hard overly thought process a bit easier..